# how to programmatically add line feeds within the tooltip of a .NET framework form

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I use my_tooltip.show( my_string, ... )
to popup details when user mouse hovers over point on my data chart.

How can I insert  within tooltip?

Comment: `my_string = "hello\r\nworld";`

Comment: Please specify the UI framework you use (WPF, WinForms, Xamarin, UWP, ASP.NET, Unity, ...)

Comment: .Net framework forms.  VS 2019 Pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem went away.   VBCRLF now works.  Don't know why it originally failed.

Answer (score 0):

Does the tooltip escape `my_string`?

If not: try using `<br>` or `\r\n` line breaks.

If yes: try using `System.Environment.NewLine`.

This may or may not work if the string is escaped.

Comment: Does not escape my_string. VBCRLF doesn't work with VB.NET.

Comment: Did System.Environment.NewLine or <br> work?